# Web Api: System.Net.Http version 2.0.0.0 not found

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-assembly, nuget-package, system.net, system.net.httpwebrequest

When I install the NuGet package for WebApi, it gives me version 1.0.0.0 of System.Net.Http, yet it references version 2.

I cannot seem to find version 2 for the life of me. When I download .net 4.5 I get System.Net.Http version 4.0.315.x, but I cannot use that because the Web Api assemblies refer to version 2.0.0.0.

Anyone know where I can find this version 2.0.0.0? I've tried the NuGet package manager, mvc4, .net 4.5, and nothing is giving me version 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I add the WebApi via NuGet, it adds `Microsoft.Net.Http` v2.0.20505.0, which also brings in `System.Net.Http` v2.0.0.0. Look in the lib folder in the packages directory.

Comment: When I go to that folder, and check the version of that System.Net.Http.dll, it's v1.0.0.0. I just removed the package and redownloaded it to be sure.

Comment: I have the reference to version 2.0.0.0, problem is I don't have the assembly. All my assemblies are either version 1.0.0.0 or 4.0.315.x.

Comment: (for future reference) If you have access to the server just install the 4.5 framework and you are done, this is how I resolve this issue... http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

Comment: just for the logs: Fileversion != Assemblyversion

Answer (score 13):

Add the below configuration inside your Web.config file under `<system.web>` node (assuming your app runs on .NET 4.5, `targetFramework` attribute is set to 4.5):

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Also add the below one at the root level under `<configuration>` node:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

This should solve your problem.