# CA0058 Error in code analysis couldnot be fxed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In my application, I am running the code analysis and there is an error in it as follows

CA0058  Error Running Code Analysis CA0058 : The referenced assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' could not be found. This assembly is required for analysis and was referenced by: C:\White Board New\WhiteBoardApp\WhiteBoardApp\bin\WhiteBoardApp.dll, C:\White Board New\WhiteBoardApp\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll. [Errors and Warnings]   (Global)

I am adding adding all the necessary assemblies but still could not fix it

Comment: Have you converted a project to a newer version of MVC? You may not require that reference any more or it might need updating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Api: System.Net.Http version 2.0.0.0 not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941447/web-api-system-net-http-version-2-0-0-0-not-found)